# starting a process in cmd window

Tags: vb.net

I have to start a process in a cmd window.
But in cases like shown because of some error cmd window just flashes and I can't see what happens. It would be the best if cmd window stay opened until some keypress or similar.

```
Dim q As String = Chr(34)
Dim p As New Process
With p.StartInfo
      .FileName = q & whereis7z & "\7z.exe" & q
      .Arguments = " e " & q & tempArch & fNameStr & q & " -y"
      .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
      .CreateNoWindow = False
      .WorkingDirectory = tempArch
       Debug.Print(.FileName & .Arguments)
End With
p.Start()
If p.ExitCode <> 0 Then
       MsgBox(p.ExitCode, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If
```

Is here any way to keep cmd window opened until keypress to see what's wrong with my 'StartInfo' because 'ExitCode' is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could redirect the standard output of the window in order to capture the program output.

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
```

Then just read in what the program has output so you can display it yourself,

```
Dim Output as String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: Wow, this is very nice! Thanks a lot! In order to use this I should set proccess info .UseShellExecute = False. And finally I can read a message from my archiver: 'cannot find archive' :)

Answer (score 1):

you should execute the cmd.com application instead of your program directly.

If you try from the start menu "cmd /k dir", you will receive the directory listing and the window will remain open.

I think you must pass your application in parameters (arguments)

Hope this helps
Serge

Comment: Well Serge, unfortunately I have to use my program :) Anyway, thanks for helping.